# Do itunes promo codes work before official release?

Tags: itunes

I have an uploaded but not yet approved paid app. When it'll be approved I'll request a promo codes. So can people download my app via these codes before it would be realesed?

Version of app is 1.0 and it's not an update.

Sorry if my question seems nooby, but i cant' find an answer.

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

Curse you, minimum character limit!

Yup: Just make sure you set the release date at some point in the future. As long as your app is pending developer release rather than review, promo codes should work. :)